# How do I change my cards back from objects in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am coding a game of War in JavaScript.  I have successfully created, shuffled and dealt a deck of cards.  Now I want each player to play a card and for them to be compared, but they are objects.  I tried .tostring and it gave me the string "Object." I tried changing from the template literal to see if that made a difference.  I tried stringify(player1.cards). Any suggestions?  It's all in JS. I tried changing the card numbers from strings to see ifthey would work if not, but no luck.  I'm going to need to compare the numbers, but figured I could the index of that array for their value.  But it looks like that's an object now.

```
class Players {
  constructor(name, cards, score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cards = [];
    this.score = score;
}
}
let player1 = new Players("Player 1");
let player2 = new Players("Player 2");

class Deck {
}
        var suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"];
        var values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"];
        var players = [[],[]]
        
        function getDeck() {
            var deck = new Array();

            for(var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++)   {
                for(var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
                    var card = {Value: values[x], Suit: suits[i]};
              deck.push(card);
        }
  } 
              return deck;
}
        function shuffle(deck) {
          for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
            var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
            var tmp = deck[location1];
              deck[location1] = deck[location2];
              deck[location2] = tmp;
                }
              }
             
              
    var deck1 = getDeck();
    shuffle(deck1); 
    console.log(deck1)
    
    //successfully shuffled deck
    dealCards(deck1)
    roundOfPlay()
    //checkForWinner()
    
function dealCards(deck1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
          let popped = deck1.pop()
          console.log(popped)
          player1.cards.push(popped)
          let popped2 = deck1.pop()
          player2.cards.push(popped2)
          }
        }

        console.log(player1.cards); 
        console.log(player2.cards);
        //SUCCESS

function roundOfPlay() {
  var card1 = player1.cards.shift();
  var card2 = player2.cards.shift();
  
  console.log("Player 1 plays the " + card1)
  console.log(`Player 2 plays the ${card2}.`)
  
  }
              }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.toString`, you should maybe try `JSON.toString(card)`

Or, you can access the card.value and compare that instead. It will be helpful to see the properties that the Card's object is build up on.